# 2 identical strings, one gives error when unserializing, the other doesn't. Why?

Tags: php, serialization

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$txt = 'a:1:{s:14:"exclude_stores";a:3:{i:0;s:7:"phoenix";i:1;s:8:"chandler";i:2;s:6:"tucson";}}' //serialized PHP array

$str = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($txt));
$str = preg_replace('/\&lt;\?.*\?\&gt;/ims', '', $str); //get rid of php tags/code enclosed in <? ... >

$str = preg_replace('/\&gt;/ims', '>', $str); //change &gt; back to >
?>
```

At this point, if I do this:

```
<?php
echo gettype($txt) . ' ' . $txt . '<br>';
echo gettype($str) . ' ' . $str;
?>
```

I get:

```
string a:1:{s:14:"exclude_stores";a:3:{i:0;s:7:"phoenix";i:1;s:8:"chandler";i:2;s:6:"tucson";}}

string a:1:{s:14:"exclude_stores";a:3:{i:0;s:7:"phoenix";i:1;s:8:"chandler";i:2;s:6:"tucson";}}
```

The strings appear to be exactly the same. Then if I do this:

```
<?php
$u1 = unserialize($txt);
print_r($u1);
$u2 = unserialize($str);
print_r($u2);
?>
```

I get:
    Array ( [exclude_stores] => Array ( [0] => phoenix [1] => chandler [2] => tucson ) )

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 5 of 128 bytes in ...
```

Something is happening to $str that unserialize doesn't like, but I can't figure out what it is. On screen the strings look exactly the same, and when I paste them in N++ they look exactly the same.

I suspect htmlspecialchars, urldecode, or preg_replace is doing something to the text I can't see. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings are different, but they appear the same on your screen because htmlspecialchars is converting to `&quot;` which renders as a " symbol on your browser screen.

Try running your script from CLI to see what I mean

$str is equal to:

```
string a:1:{s:14:&quot;exclude_stores&quot;;a:3:{i:0;s:7:&quot;phoenix&quot;;i:1;s:8:&quot;chandler&quot;;i:2;s:6:&quot;tucson&quot;;}}
```

You can see why it won't unserialize :)

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!